# Multiple Market using of an freemium Purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, multiplatform, amazon-appstore

my idea is to have an free app on more then one market:

Amazon Market Place, Google Play Store, Samsung App Store, Samsung Account Service like Smart TV and Facebook App Store.

If a user does the app install on a Android Device and buys it in the Google Play Store and likes to use it on his Amazon Kindle too.
How can i achieve it that the user can use his buyed in app purchase of the premium membership from the Google Play Store on his Amazon Kindle?

I don't want to force a rebuy for the second market that he wants to use.

Is that possible or isn't it allowed?

Recap: Buying the Premium Membership in a Google Play Store downloaded Version of my app and using this Membership in the same app of the Amazon App Store.

Comment: you could make the premium fetaures passoible via an inapp purchase, if he purchases the premium features ask him for a login, store that on your server. No you can provide him a "get premium" on every market with the posssibility to "login" on your server and ask this server if he purchased premium

Comment: @A.S. u mean i should store every user in my own database and remember the used login account and then get the purchase from the market of his loginaccount?

Comment: With this option your user can get the "Premium Features" Via a verified login from you server, if the server say "Yes he is Premium" then you could make the premium features available. but the disadvantage is that the users need to remember their login to this. Because Amazon has other useraccount than google, so they need to know their login for your service

Comment: @A.S. or i remember the used accounts? he can link several accounts to an existing and verify it

Comment: you could give it a try of course

Comment: @A.S. 
Is once that possible? if i check the purchase of the google account on amazon store app they will ignore my request to google?

Comment: some amazon device do not even have a google account (kindle fire) keep that in mind